# "Towers" on singular cardinals with countable cofinality

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, infinite-combinatorics, pcf-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a singular cardinal of countable cofinality.

Is there necessarily a sequence $\{A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda^+\}$ of countable subsets of $\lambda$, such that $\alpha<\beta$ if and only if $A_\alpha\setminus A_\beta$ is finite?

In other words, we know that for $\omega$, there is an uncountable sequence of subsets which is increasing modulo finite changes. Is the same true for other cardinals of countable cofinality?

Comment: I've put tower in quotation marks since I would expect towers to be in $\mathcal P(\lambda)$ and modulo the bounded ideal, rather than countable subsets modulo finite. I've also tentatively put the [tag:pcf] tag since I feel it might have something to do with the answer.

Comment: Can you please give an increasing modulo finite changes uncountable sequence of subsets of $\omega$.
Thanks.

Comment: @Joel: No, since it requires the axiom of choice. But even without choice you can prove that a sequence of coinfinite subsets of $\omega$ has a coinfinite set almost containing all of them. Therefore by Zorn's Lemma there is an uncountable tower.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Assuming that by co-infinite you mean "complement is infinite". Let $X_n$ be the set of all odd numbers for $n$ odd, and let $X_n$ be the set of all even numbers for $n$ even. Then there is no co-infinite set containing almost all of the $X_n$, right? Or did you mean by "... you can prove that a sequence...": "you can prove that *there is a sequence* of co-infinite sets such that..."?

Comment: @Dominic: I meant an increasing sequence. Not just any sequence. And in the case where you talk about partitions, then you want to talk about something almost disjoint from all the parts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you give a hint on how to construct that set almost containing all of the increasing sequence of coinfinite subsets?

Comment: @Dominic: Diagonalize. Take all the members of the $n$th set which are also larger than $n$, or something like that. If you're careful enough, you can be sure that the result is coinfinite (by leaving gaps so you always also not-add some number).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $\lambda > 2^{\aleph_0}$, there is no such sequence.

Suppose $\lambda > 2^{\aleph_0}$. Because $2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot have countable cofinality, there is some $\kappa < \lambda$ with $2^{\aleph_0} < \kappa$. Consider the sequence $\{A_\alpha \cap A_\kappa \mid \alpha < \kappa\}$. For each particular $\alpha$, the sets $A_\alpha$ and $A_\alpha \cap A_\kappa$ differ by only finitely many elements. Each set of this form is a countable subset of the countable set $A_\kappa$, so there are fewer than $\kappa$ possibilities for the sets $A_\alpha \cap A_\kappa$. Thus we may find $\alpha < \beta < \kappa$ such that $A_\alpha \cap A_\kappa = A_\beta \cap A_\kappa$. But then $A_\alpha$ and $A_\beta$ differ by only finitely many elements, and in particular we have $A_\beta \setminus A_\alpha$ finite while $\alpha < \beta$, contrary to your condition.