# Can the union of difference sets in towers equal $\omega$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

We write $A\subseteq^* B$ if $A\setminus B$ is finite.

Let $(A_n)_{n\in\omega}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\omega$ such that for all $n\in\omega$ we have $A_n \subseteq^* A_{n+1}$ and $A_{n+1}\not\subseteq^* A_n$.

Let $D_n:= A_{n+1}\setminus A_n$ for all $n\in\omega$. Is it possible that $$\bigcup_{n\in\omega} D_n = \omega?$$

Comment: Did you mean to ask about $A_n\setminus A_{n+1}$?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks -- I did mean $A_{n+1}\setminus A_n$ because I wanted to use the union of all these difference sets to construct a co-infinite "top" element to all the $A_n$'s because I wanted to show that a countable tower cannot be maximal. This originated in that question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290921/towers-on-singular-cardinals-with-countable-cofinality?noredirect=1#comment767869_290921 but then I was able to construct a "top" element in another way (https://dominiczypen.wordpress.com/2018/08/20/basics-on-towers-in-latex-omega/ ).

Comment: But with $A_{n+1}-A_n$, it is much easier, since you can do it with $\subseteq$ instead of $\subseteq$. Just partition $\omega$ into $\omega$ many infinite sets, and let $A_n$ be the first $n$ pieces. The difference sets $A_{n+1}-A_n$ are the pieces of the partition, which union to $\omega$.

Comment: Oh -- thanks for your help on this!

Comment: I had meant to write: $\subseteq$ instead of $\subseteq^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any increasing tower, but then modify it by adding all the numbers below $n$ to $A_n$, when $n$ is even, and removing them when $n$ is odd. This is a finite change to each set in the tower, and so it doesn't affect any $\subseteq^*$ relation, but now every number will eventually appear in the difference sets, jumping in and then out again at every other step.